# Is there a link between Radon Measure and Radon-Nikodym theorem?

Tags: measure-theory

Is there a link between Radon Measure and Radom-Nikodym theorem ? May be that a Radon measure is "derivable" ? Moreover, what is the principal motivation for radon measure ?

Comment: [This is for the motivation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure#Motivation)

Comment: That should be *Radon*-Nikodym theorem. The measure and the theorem are both named after Austrian mathematician Johann Radon.

Comment: Perhaps merely that they are both named for Otton Nikodym, Polish mathematician.